# Nvidia Optimus on 13.10 Use initial Support or Bumblebee?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, 13.10

After upgrading to 13.10 and reading this post: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html im wondering if the "initial optimus support" from nvidia or the bumblebee soulution brings better performance. I didnt understand how the inital support works. As mentioned in the post, GTK2 theming in firefox seems to be broking somehow.

Does everyone have a quick info what is recommended right now with 13.10?

Answer (score 1):

The well named "initial support", is an initial support. Basically that means you could use full power of your optimus graphic card without no need of bumblebee/prime.
But, you will soon notice that battery life will strongly decrease (In my case around 1h).

I would recommend you to keep bumblebee installed to keep a "normal" battery life.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Though the battery-increase may be higher, i will stick to the initial support.The old firefox lock is a bit anoying , but i think this will be fixed soon. Furthermore all my steam games are working perfectly, so i can enjoy playing some dota and stuff. I can hardly complain :) One more question. The Intel Gpu is in use while using the normal desktop, is it? It's not like the whole system is being rendered by the nvidia gpu or?

Comment: @Wrigley I think the whole system is being rendered by the nvidia gpu.